# Radiobutton list and Checkbox list validation do not work in razor page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a razor view page that I am trying to validate if user does not checked radio button or checkbox list. Right now, only textbox will return error message if user leaves blank, radiobuttonlist, checkboxlist don't fire up. I have added [Required] in the model class column field. I have no clue what the problem is in my razor view. The below code in razor page does not show the error message if user does not select one of the options. Please help.

```
<input id="Ethnicity" type="radio" name="Ethnicity" value="Yes" />Yes
<input id="Ethnicity" type="radio" name="Ethnicity" value="No" />No
<span asp-validation-for="Ethnicity" class="text-danger"></span>
```

The controller receives the checked value if user has selected one of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like:

```
@Html.Label("YES")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Ethnicity, "YES")
@Html.Label("NO")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Ethnicity, "NO")
<span asp-validation-for="Ethnicity" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Now it can validate radio button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. I have not tested the checkboxlist yet. Is it the same?